# Gradle - Use local JDK's features

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, java-8, build.gradle

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA and have automatically imported @Nullable:

```
import com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable;
```

when I jump to the definition of this anno it is somewhere in the local jdk (located at JAVA_HOME).
That's the only SDK i have and Gradle surely has to use this for compilation etc., however I get an error:

```
:compileJava
D:\src\ensembl-ftp-search\src\main\java\ebi\ensembl\ftpsearchapi\LinkSpecificationsIntersector.java:3: 
error: package com.sun.istack.internal does not exist
import com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable;
```

Is there anything I have to configure in Gradle for it to be able to "see" dependencies & imports from local JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the dependency in your `build.gradle` as below:

```
dependencies{
   compile 'org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.12'
}
```

**IF** you meet the same problem at the next time, you can search dependencies in [maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav).